# dataframe plot_ly zero not aligned

Tags: r

I am a little bit new to R plot_ly and have an issue with a graph. 
I have constructed a dataframe with values for different dates depending on the column. My dataframe has dates in the first column and then values for the different dates but not necessarily on all dates. Hence I am using na.locf to remove na between 2 values by the first value (hope I am clear enough). The remaining na are the ones before the first value for each column, which I then replace by 0. 
Then I am trying to plot my df with the dates on the x axis and the evolution of my time series on the y axis. 
My issue is that somehow there is some difference between 0 values for one of my graph (see screenshot) The orange line begins at 0 and then has some values. If I put the mouse on the graph, before the "big drop", the value is shown to be 0, after it is 0.00. The df has no values for this time serie at this point. Also the graphs does not seem to have the same y axis even if they should and I no not understand why.

My code to create the graph is:

```
  if (dim(df1)[1] != 0){

  df1 <- na.locf(df1)

  df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0.00

  all_names <- colnames(df1)[-1]

  for (i in all_names){
    if (i==all_names[1]){
      p <- plot_ly(x = df1$date, y= df1[,i] , name = i, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    }else{
      p <- p %>% add_trace(y = df1[,i], name = i, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    }

  }


  output$info_graph <- renderPlotly({
    p
  })

  output$info_output <- renderUI({
    plotlyOutput("info_graph")
  })

}else{
  output$info_output <- renderUI({
  })
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I have added a screenshot of my data where the gap is (orange line is the third column (before the 2008-09-12 I only have NA), blue one is the second column:
[image]

EDIT2: I just reproduced with 26 dates. You can see the screenshot:
[image]

dput gives:

```
    structure(list(date = structure(c(14062, 14069, 14076, 14083, 
14090, 14097, 14104, 14111, 14118, 14125, 14132, 14134, 14139, 
14141, 14146, 14148, 14153, 14155, 14160, 14162, 14167, 14169, 
14174, 14176, 14181, 14183), class = "Date"), col1 = c(3036258.57195313, 
3023427.6675, 2971520.82675781, 3093997.64199219, 3042965.63564453, 
3119076.22796875, 3154652.82667969, 3120534.28529297, 3101871.15154297, 
3226680.85849609, 3185563.64195312, NA, 3077375.78849609, NA, 
3039466.29806641, NA, 2956357.03058594, NA, 2701488.6103125, 
NA, 2715194.34916016, NA, 2687199.64853516, NA, 2733857.48291016, 
NA), col2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0)), .Names = c("date", 
"col1", "col2"), row.names = 145:170, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: could you provide the data?

Comment: I will try but the dataframe is very big...! How would it be the best to provide them?

Comment: It would be best if you could reproduce the problem with a subset of the data - like 50 rows or less, then use `dput(data1)` and paste the output to the question. Then provide the graph for just that data subset.

Comment: just did in the EDIT2

Comment: I provided the answer. Check please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are plotting character variables which are converted to categorical in the plot call. The culprit is the mis(s)use of `na.locf` function.

The first column of your data frame is a character column, when you provide the whole data frame to `na.locf` it converts everything to character. Here is a fix:

```
library(zoo)
library(plotly)
```

convert the date column to `POSIXct`

```
df1$date <- as.POSIXct(df1$date)
```

use `na.locf` only on numerical columns

```
df1[,2:3] <- na.locf(df1[,2:3])
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0.00

for (i in all_names){
  if (i==all_names[1]){
    p <- plot_ly(x = df1$date, y= df1[,i] , name = i, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
  }else{
    p <- p %>% add_trace(y = df1[,i], name = i, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
  }

}
p
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine! As my number of columns is not always 2, I have used the following: df1[,2:dim(df1)[2]] <- na.locf(df1[,2:dim(df1)[2]]) but the rest is perfect! again thanks a lot!